# Python: Find tuples with greatest total distinct values

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples of integers.

I would like to return a new list containing some (or all) of these tuples such that total number of integers is largest and no single integer is repeated.

```
my_tuples = [(1,2), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4), (3,4,5,6), (4,5), (8,9)]
getGreatestCoverage(my_tuples) 
# expected output is [(1,2), (3,4,5,6), (8,9)]
```

NB. The above mentioned "expected output" contains a total of 8 integers, with no repeating integer.
I can achieve the desired results by limiting the number of tuples to output to 2:

```
def getGreatestCoverage_for_2_tuples(my_tuples):
    max_cover = 0
    for idx1, item1 in enumerate(my_tuples):
        for item2 in my_tuples[idx1+1:]:
            coverage = len(set(item1 + item2))
            if coverage >= max_cover:
                max_cover = coverage
                greatest_coverage = (item1, item2)
```

This works fine if the aim is to return exactly 2 tuples. If the aim were to return exactly 3 tuples, another internal for-loop could be added.
This does not satisfy the intention because I would like any number of tuples to be allowed as a possible output.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want there.. what is the expected output for your example?

Comment: @user8408080 The expected output is indicated in the question (as a comment). I will further clarify.

Comment: Okay so what is the definition of a "group" here?

Comment: @user8408080 I have edited the question, replacing the word "group" by "list of tuples". I hope it is more clear.

Comment: ..or the longest ascending series of numbers? You need to be clearer

Comment: @user8408080 I have edited the question in an attempt to be clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but it's the only one I have right now:

```
import itertools

#a = [(1,2), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4), (3,4,5,6), (4,5), (8,9)]
#a = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (5,6), (6,7), (8,), (9, 10)]
a = [(0, 1, 2), (0,1), (1,2), (3,4), (4,5)]

def find_largest_group(x):
    max_ = 0
    max_len = max(map(max, x)) -  min(map(min, x)) + 1

    for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
        b = itertools.combinations(x, i)
        for tups in b:
            m = len(set.union(*map(set, tups)))
            if m==len(tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(tups))):
                if m==max_len:
                    max_tups = tups
                    break
                else:
                    if m > max_:
                        max_ = m
                        max_tups = tups
    return max_tups
```

output:

```
In [68]: find_largest_group(a)
Out[68]: ((0, 1, 2), (3, 4))
```

Comment: @RyanLague So, does it work for your test cases?

Comment: Nearly! I can't quite figure out when the issue is yet... But the following input: [(0, 1, 2), (0,1), (1,2), (3,4), (4,5)] Outputs ((0, 1, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5))

Comment: @RyanLague I fixed it; it should now work properly

Answer (score -1):

He said that if they don't have repeating items, so the set won't give us the right result as if there is a tuple that has 10 elements but two are repeating (with a set it will have 9 elements) it should not be included. Following this logic, the best solution is to filter those tuples right away.

```
my_tuples = [(1,2), (2,3,4), (1,2,3,4), (3,4,5,6,1,2,7,5,6), (4,5), (8,9)]
print(max([i for i in my_tuples if len(i)==len(set(i))], key=lambda x: len(x)))
```