# Quickly find subset of list of lists with greatest total distinct elements

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

Given a list of lists of tuples, I would like to find the subset of lists which maximize the number of distinct integer values without any integer being repeated.

The list looks something like this:

```
x = [
         [(1,2,3), (8,9,10), (15,16)],
         [(2,3), (10,11)],
         [(9,10,11), (17,18,19), (20,21,22)],
         [(4,5), (11,12,13), (18,19,20)]
    ]
```

The internal tuples are always sequential --> (1,2,3) or (15,16), but they may be of any length.

In this case, the expected return would be:

```
maximized_list = [
                  [(1, 2, 3), (8, 9, 10), (15, 16)], 
                  [(4, 5), (11, 12, 13), (18, 19, 20)]
                 ]
```

This is valid because in each case:

1. Each internal list of x remains intact
2. There is a maximum number of distinct integers (16 in this case)
3. No integer is repeated.

If there are multiple valid solutions, all should be return in a list.

I have a naive implementation of this, heavily based on a previous stackoverflow question I had asked, which was not as well formed as it could have been ([Python: Find tuples with greatest total distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611880/python-find-tuples-with-greatest-total-distinct-values)):

```
import itertools

def maximize(self, x):
    max_ = 0
    possible_patterns = []

    for i in range(1, len(x)+1):
        b = itertools.combinations(x, i)

        for combo in b:
            all_ints = tuple(itertools.chain(*itertools.chain(*combo)))
            distinct_ints = tuple(set(all_ints))

            if sorted(all_ints) != sorted(distinct_ints):
                continue
            else:
                if len(all_ints) >= max_:
                    if len(all_ints) == max_:
                        possible_patterns.append(combo)
                        new_max = len(all_ints)
                    elif len(all_ints) > max_:
                        possible_patterns = [combo]
                        new_max = len(all_ints)
                    max_ = new_max

    return possible_patterns
```

The above-mentioned function appears to give me the correct result, but does not scale. I will need to accept x values with a few thousand lists (possibly as many as tens of thousands), so an optimized algorithm is required.

Comment: What's the significance of the internal tuple? It seems like each list could just be a list of numbers rather than pairs of numbers?

Comment: Also are the internal tuples always n and n+1?

Comment: Also are the tuples always ordered within the list?

Comment: @Carlos it is acceptable to assume that the tuples are always ordered if that makes the problem easier.

Comment: @Carlos the internal tuples are always sequential, but not always n and n+1 alone. I have changed the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solves for the maximal subset of sublists, with respect to cardinality. It works by flattening each sublist, constructing a list of sets of intersections between the sublists, and then searches the solution space in a depth-first-search for the solution with the most elements (i.e. largest "weight").

```
def maximize_distinct(sublists):
    subsets = [{x for tup in sublist for x in tup} for sublist in sublists]

    def intersect(subset):
        return {i for i, sset in enumerate(subsets) if subset & sset}

    intersections = [intersect(subset) for subset in subsets]
    weights = [len(subset) for subset in subsets]

    pool = set(range(len(subsets)))
    max_set, _ = search_max(pool, intersections, weights)
    return [sublists[i] for i in max_set]

def search_max(pool, intersections, weights):
    if not pool: return [], 0

    max_set = max_weight = None
    for num in pool:
        next_pool = {x for x in pool - intersections[num] if x > num}
        set_ids, weight = search_max(next_pool, intersections, weights)

        if not max_set or max_weight < weight + weights[num]:
            max_set, max_weight = [num] + set_ids, weight + weights[num]
    return max_set, max_weight
```

This code can be optimized further by keeping a running total of the "weights" (sum of cardinalities of sublists) discarded, and pruning that branch of the search space when it exceeds that of the maximal solution so far (which will be the minimal discard weight). Unless you run into performance problems however, this will likely be more work than its worth, and for a small list of lists the overhead of the computation will exceed the speedup of pruning.

Comment: Passing my example x value above to maximize_distinct(), I get an error on the last "if statement" in search_max(): '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'. It seems that the max_weight is sometimes None on this line. I changed the line **max_set = max_weight = None** to **max_set = max_weight = 0**. It appears to work now.

Comment: @RyanLague yeah, I reordered the conditions in that if statement since `not max_set` fails all but the first iteration, but didn't think about type errors. Either switching the arguments back or using `0` instead of `None` will fix it.

Comment: edited to revert the if-statement to a working state