# Find subset of sentences that maximize unique words

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Say I have Set S which is some set of sentences. A sentence can be defined as a `string[]`

I want to find subset U of S of size N such that U maximizes the number of unique words. That is, no other subset of S of size N could have as many unique words as subset U.

I am wondering if there is a more computationally optimal way than building all combinations of size N of S then selecting the one which maximizes unique words.

Any nudges or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A greedy algorithm would seem to be useful here.  However, I don't think that it is necessarily optimal.  That is, could it be proven that the maximum set of size N always includes a maximum set of size N - 1.  It may be easy to construct a counter example for N = 2.

Comment: I did consider a greedy algorithm, if nothing else comes up I may go with that.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725354/quickly-find-subset-of-list-of-lists-with-greatest-total-distinct-elements

Comment: Is it not possible to find all unique words, map each sentence as a "boolean" vector tracking those unique words, then sort those vectors by numbers of 1 found, and take the first n ones?